# Close plot window in rasterio using command line

Tags: python, rasterio

I am using the `rasterio` package in python and trying to do some simple plotting. I am trying to iterate over a number of tiffs, but can't figure out how to close the pyplot window generated using the `show` command in `rasterio`. Here is some example code:

```
f = 'C:\\path\\to\\tiff.tif'
rast = rasterio.open(f)
show(rast)
outfile = "C:\\outfile\\outfilename.png"
plt.savefig(outfile)
plt.close()
rast.close()
```

However, this does not close the pyplot window. I am using python within a conda environment and within VSCode. I have tested it at a simple command prompt as well. The issue is that `show` locks up the command prompt. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Just don't call `show()` if all you're trying to do is save the image to disk.  If you want to show the plot for some amount of time before automatically moving on, you'll have to look into matplotlib's interactive mode: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.isinteractive.html#matplotlib.pyplot.isinteractive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, `rast` is the file-handle... `rast.close()` will only release the file and has nothing to do with the plot.

- `plt.close()` will close the most recent figure
- `plt.close("all")` will close all figures
- `plt.close(fig)` will close the provided figure

from your code, i guess that `show(rast)` already creates a figure (not sure because you don't include what `show` is but I guess it's `rasterio.plot.show`)...
`plt.savefig(...)` will then create an additional figure which might be why you end up with an open figure in the end.

the best solution would be to use the axis-object returned by `show` (e.g. `ax=show(raster)`) and then simply call `ax.figure.savefig(...)` and `plt.close(ax.figure)` to close it.

---

If you only want to save the figure and do not want to show the figure at all, switch to a non-gui backend (it will also be faster)...

Something like this should do the job:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use("agg")

f = 'C:\\path\\to\\tiff.tif'
outfile = "C:\\outfile\\outfilename.png"

with rasterio.open(f) as rast:
    ax = show(rast)   # show returns the axes NOT the figure!
    ax.figure.savefig(outfile)
```

Comment: 'matplotlib.use("agg")` did the trick! I didn't need to GUI.